# Retrieve original JSON request in case of 500 HTTP error in a REST WS

Tags: json, rest, web-services, jakarta-ee, cxf

Is there any way to get the original JSON object that was received in a REST WS PUT request in case of 500 Error?

Here is my WS interface :

```
public interface VehicleConnectedMileageApi {
    public Response updateConnectedVehiclemileage(@ApiParam(value = "vehicle" ,required=true ) Vehicle vehicle)
  throws NotFoundException;
}
```

In my application-context xml file i use the following to define the WS :

```
<!-- For VehicleConnectedMileage  -->
<jaxrs:server id="VehicleConnectedMileageREST" address="/mileageManagement">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="VehicleConnectedMileageApiImpl" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="com.europcar.gwy.fleet.utils.error.RuntimeExceptionMapperHandler" />
        <bean class="com.europcar.gwy.fleet.utils.error.MappingDataExceptionMapper" />
        <bean id="jacksonObjectMapperProvider" class="com.europcar.gwy.fleet.utils.providers.JacksonObjectMapperProvider" />
        <bean id="dateParameterConverterProvider" class="com.europcar.gwy.fleet.utils.providers.DateParamConverterProvider" />
        <bean id="jacksonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>

</jaxrs:server>
```

But in those providers and mappers above there is no way to acces the Vehicle object received in the first time.

This is ana example of the RuntimeExceptionMapper used :

```
@Provider
public class RuntimeExceptionMapperHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>{

/** The invalid Data id. */
private String INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_ID = ""; // TODO which error Id

private String INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_MSG = ""; // TODO which error message
/** The invalid data or content  desc. */
private String INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_DESC = "An error has occurred during the processing of your request"; // TODO which error desc

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper#toResponse(java.lang.Throwable)
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Response toResponse(Exception pEx) {
    return ErrorResponseBuilder.prepareInternalServerErrorRequestResponse(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_ID, INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_DESC,INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_MSG).build();
}
}
```

But inside this there is no way to get The vehicle received in the first place

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple `ContainerRequestFilter` and include into your providers. Inside the filter method you can get the request.

```
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class RequestInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter
{
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException
    {       
        System.out.println("Filter executed.");
    }
}
```